# Runscope init timestamp variable before every request

Tags: javascript, initialization, runscope

I am using Initial Script to initialize few variables, one of them is a UTC timestamp connected value. I have 5 requests in my Test, first requests executed correct but last are not, because time connected variable is expired for API I test. I mean while first tests executed this variable is expired because my API is time sensitive.

Can I initialize some variables before every request, but not before all of them?

I know that I can create separate tests for every request but it's not cool and I want to hold all of them under one test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to update that variable with the current UTC at the ​*end*​ of each request using a script. You typically use the script to perform assertions; however, you can also use `variable.set` in a request's script.

Another way is to use the `{{timestamp}}` function which returns the unix timestamp/epoch (seconds, not milliseconds).

If you require the ISO-8601 format of UTC, you can also use `{{utc_datetime}}`.

Comment: It works, thanks. BTW, looks like `{{timestamp}}` returns not UTC timestamp, or I am wrong?

Comment: ```{{utc_datetime}}``` appended to answer. ISO-8601. This along with a bunch of other nice helper functions you get with Runscope are listed [here](https://www.runscope.com/docs/api-testing/variables).